# How to calculate percentage in a calculator that takes whole input as a String?

Tags: java, android, stack

```
public static int applyOp(char op, int b, int a) {
    switch (op) {
        case '+':
            return a + b;
        case '-':
            return a - b;
        case '*':
            return a * b;
        case '%':
            return a % b;  //But this doesn't work properly.
        case '/':
            if (b == 0)
                throw new
                        UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot divide by zero");
            return a / b;
    }
    return 0;
}

}
```

i tried this using 100*10+2, 525+5%, 525*5%  but other operators work properly but '%' doesn't.

Comment: `%` is the modulus operator, you can't use it for calculating percentages. If all your operators work properly and you want a quick solution you could pre-process your string replacing `%` with `/100`(i.e. `525*5%` becomes `525*5/100`) - *beware integer division!*

Comment: In what way does it not work *"properly"*? Have you done some debugging to see in what way it misbehaves?

Comment: What output do you expect for, say, `17 % 5`?

Comment: Actually the thing is I've taken input as a string(like "525*15%") and wanted to pass in this method to calculate. I am very confused, any suggestion please....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int applyOp(char op, int b, int a) {
    switch (op) {
        case '+':
            return a + b;
        case '-':
            return a - b;
        case '*':
            return a * b;
        case '%':

            return (int)(((float) a / b) * 100);
        case '/':
            if (b == 0)
                throw new
                        UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot divide by zero");
            return a / b;
    }
    return 0;
}

}
```

while using `%` it will return the `modulus` [remainder] for the division `a` by `b`

Answer (score 0):

`%` operator computes a reminder and not percentage.

If you want to compute 'how many percents is `a` of `b`?', you could use something like this:

```
(int) (((float) a / b) * 100)
```

You need to cast to `float` to use floating point division instead of integer division (that would be used for just `a/b`) to not loose precision before multiplying by 100.

Another option is to multiply first:

```
a * 100 / b
```

But here you could potentially get an integer overflow if `a` is large in magnitude.